# WSO2 Ant CAR build task

Tags: wso2

I understand that WSO2 provides Maven plugin for building CAR files from command line.

Our organization uses ANT instead of Maven. And I noticed that WSO2 provides Ant Deployer task. Do they offer an Ant task for building CAR files as well?

Another question: is there any documentation on the CAR file structure?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Carbon Application aRchives (CAR) file to deploy applications to any WSO2 Carbon-based servers.

CAR files can be created from Carbon Application (C-App) projects.

C-App is an Aggregator Project for deploying items such as Axis2 services, ESB configurations, web apps etc.

A C-App artifact has a name, version and a (server) role. Such as EnterpriseServiceBus and ApplicationServer. Likewise, a C-App can have many artifacts. You can use [WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) to create C-Apps easily. You choose the option to create a Carbon application in WSO2 Developer Studio dashboard once you have some applications for WSO2 Carbon based servers. Then you can right click the project and export as a CAR file.

The root of CAR file has the artifacts.xml, which describes each artifact in sub directories (sub projects) and dependencies. Each artifact directory also has an artifact.xml.

You can find information about CAR file from following links.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Browsing+Applications

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Carbon410/Introduction+to+Server+Roles

AFAIK, there is no ANT plugin to offer similar functionality.